# Value of Angular ui-select

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-select

In my application have ui-select:

```
<ui-select ng-model="flat.flatData.type_local" theme="bootstrap">
   <ui-select-match placeholder="Type">
      {{ $select.selected.type }}
   </ui-select-match>
   <ui-select-choices repeat="t in flat.type_local | filter: $select.search">
      {{ t.type }}
   </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

After chosing something i want to add value of select to database.

Before i'm using input and dont have a problem with adding to database.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="type" ng-model="flat.flatData.type_local" placeholder="Type" required>
```

This is part of my controller:

```
angular.module('flatCtrl', ['flatService', 'ui.grid', 'ui.grid.resizeColumns', 'ui.grid.moveColumns', 'ui.grid.autoResize', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.select'])
.controller('FlatController', function(Flat, socketio){

    vm = this;

    vm.createFlat = function(){
        vm.message = '';
        Flat.create(vm.flatData)
            .success(function(data){

                // clear up the form
                vm.flatData = '';
                vm.message = data.message;
            });
    };


    vm.type_local = [
        { type: 'One' },
        { type: 'Two' }
    ];
```

Comment: whats not working exactly?

Comment: When i click submit i don't have value of this select in database. Don't have flat.flatData.type_local

Comment: if i using input, i don't have a problem

Comment: in input you specified `"flat.flatData.type_local"` and in view its `flat.type_local`, you sure you are binding correctly

Comment: can you give bit more information, question in not really clear enough, what do you mean by database, are calling AJAX service and its not firing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the fix to this issue:

```
 <ui-select-choices repeat="t.type as t in flat.type_local track by $index | filter: $select.search">
```

and

```
 <div ng-bind-html="t.type | highlight: $select.search"></div>
```

Comment: in <p>Selected: {{ flat.flatData.type_local }}</p> i have "Selected: {"type":"One"}" May this is problem?

Comment: You mean you have a pre-selected option?  I'm not very familiar with ui-select but in a regular selection I would use ng-init to set a pre selected option. I updated the jsfiddle. It doesn't affect the form submission. Try to remove and test it.

Comment: no, "Selected: {"type":"One"}" i have after chosing option. In your code you  have "Selected: One"

Comment: ahh I get it. It could be.

Comment: Can you console.log your data vm.flatData before Flat.create(vm.flatData). like I said before maybe something to do with the data you are sending.

Comment: in console i have something like this - position1: 1, position2: 2, position3: 3, type_local: Object$$hashKey: "object:21"type: "One"......where is position - it's inputs

Comment: value of every input - is a string, and value of my select is object with key and value

Comment: That is the issue. you have to have the select as a string as well. Review your ui-select structure.  Can you test to add track by $index. <ui-select-choices repeat="t in flat.type_local track by $index | filter: $select.search"> or maybe track by type so you will have the right value.

Comment: not working...trying to do something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28142929/angular-ui-selet-how-to-bind-only-selected-value-to-ng-model

Comment: but dont know how to do it in my project

Comment: Here are the changes you have to implement.     <ui-select-choices repeat="t.type as t in flat.type_local track by $index | filter: $select.search">         and         <div ng-bind-html="t.type | highlight: $select.search"></div>

Comment: @MartijnPieters I guess you didn't have time to read the comments. The code to fix was posted only 2 comments above yours not in the fiddle. This point down came as a surprise as Eugeniusz and I spent a good amount of time trying to figure this out in the dark because he couldn't show more code. Anyway base on the "-1" punishment I figured out that the right answer were a bit lost in the comments so I decided to open another answer to give it more visibility. At the end of the day we are not here for the points but to help each other right ;-)

Comment: @CarlaFrança: solutions don't really belong in comments; you can just *edit* your existing answer to update it (I've done so for you now). You could try and *explain* why your solution works, currently it is just a (small) code-dump without any explanation as to why this is the fix.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="type" 
       ng-model="flat.type_local" placeholder="Type" required>
```

Comment: Input is working, problem when i use select instead of input

Comment: in input you specified `"flat.flatData.type_local"` and in view its `flat.type_local`, you sure you are binding correctly in `<ui-select-choices repeat="t in flat.type_local | filter: $select.search">`

Comment: flatData using when create object   vm.create = function(){
            vm.message = '';
            Flat.create(vm.flatData)
                .success(function(data){

                    // clear up the form
                    vm.flatData = '';
                    vm.message = data.message;
                });
        };